# "Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hi I'm supposed to make a website for school using vue,

I've included vue in the head of the html using:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

When I try to create a new vue (as a script in html and as a .js file):

```
var vuetop = new vue({
    el: '#vuetop',
        data: {
            dat: null
        },
        created: function() {
            fetch("/data/topnews.json")
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(tdat => {
                    this.dat = tdat;
                })
        }
    })
```

I always get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `Vue` not `vue`, the first letter `V` should be an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the oficial vue example in this link (https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chrisvfritz/7f8d7d63000b48493c336e48b3db3e52/raw/ed60c4e5d5c6fec48b0921edaed0cb60be30e87c/index.html)

But maybe only changing vue to Vue like the other answers will solve your problem.